# UISwitch not Working Properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift2

In my code I'm storing the `UISwitch` state via `NSUserDefaults`. But when the Window reloads the all `UISwitche's` are turned on. Here is my snippet of code:

```
   @IBAction func switchState(sender: AnyObject) {

    let standardDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()    
    if mySwitch.on{
        standardDefaults.setObject("On", forKey: "switchKey")
    }
    else{   
        standardDefaults.setObject("Off", forKey: "switchKey")   
    }
    standardDefaults.synchronize()

}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let standardDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    self.mySwitch.on = standardDefaults.stringForKey("switchKey") == "On"
}
```

I believe it is in the `awakeFromNib` section but I cannot figure it out. Please Help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is redundant code in your implementation. You can directly save `bool` in `NSUserDefaults` rather than storing `String` and later on manipulating it.

This is how you should do it:

**While saving data:**

```
@IBAction func switchState(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(mySwitch.on, forKey: "switchKey")
}
```

**While retrieving data:**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.mySwitch.on = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("switchKey")
}
```

Also, it is worth noting that `NSUserDefaults` starts empty, so asking for a key returns `nil`, and calling `boolValue` on `nil` returns `false`. If you want your switch to start off with a default value you can implement this in `appDidFinishLaunching`:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["switchKey" : true])
```

Comment: There is no need to call `synchronize`

Comment: Hey thanks guys. Real quick this will save the switch state but when the table reloads the individual states of the switches are not saved. They are all on or off depending on the state of one or all switches example:  I go into the table and turn one of four switches on. I then go to the next window and come back and all 4 switches are on. If I turn all switches off and go away and come back all switches remain off. Do I need to store individual row values? If so what is the best way to do that?

Comment: I thought you had only one switch. If you have multiple switches you can trick it by saving a dictionary in user defaults with key as some unique test to uniquely identity a switch and value as state of the switch.

Comment: @Abhinav Got it working finally I did use a `NSDictionary` but did not store the values to `NSUserDefaults` I instead looped through the dictionary then tested the values with an `if statement` and used `.setOn` works perfect now thanks for the help again it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Great...  Considering the suggestion, can this answer be accepted?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.mySwitch.on = standardDefaults.stringForKey("switchKey") == "On"
```

should be

```
self.mySwitch.on = (standardDefaults.stringForKey("switchKey") == "On")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  self.mySwitch.on = standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "on")
```

I hope it help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PetroKorienev How does this not provide an answer? It presents a plausible solution. If you believe it is incorrect, you should downvote and leave a comment explaining your concerns.

Comment: Consider adding one-two words of explanation, why author's code is wrong and your snippet is right instead.